# Postgres Log : "using stale statistics instead of current ones because stats collector is not responding"

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

Hace una par de semanas migramos nuestro Postgresql v.10 a Postgresql v.14, usamos como instrumento de monitoreo PgBadger y desde hace unos días pudimos notar que este error Log: "using stale statistics instead of current ones because stats collector is not responding" se repte con frecuencia. Mi pregunta es:

1. Cuál podría ser la causa?
2. Qué impacto tiene en datos que vemos en el PgBadger?
3. Es un error que debe preocuparnos?

Muchas Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Ese error normalmente se da por la forma en que el recolector de estadísticas trabaja, que tiene que colectar información y escribirla en alguna parte generando algo de IO, pero el sistema está tan ocupado en altos periodos de carga que no puede terminar la actividad o algo no lo deja terminar (tal vez otro proceso o pocos recursos).

[PG 14 documentación](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/monitoring-stats.html#MONITORING-STATS-SETUP)

> The statistics collector transmits the collected information to other PostgreSQL processes through temporary files. These files are stored in the directory named by the stats_temp_directory parameter, pg_stat_tmp by default. For better performance, stats_temp_directory can be pointed at a RAM-based file system, decreasing physical I/O requirements. When the server shuts down cleanly, a permanent copy of the statistics data is stored in the pg_stat subdirectory, so that statistics can be retained across server restarts. When recovery is performed at server start (e.g., after immediate shutdown, server crash, and point-in-time recovery), all statistics counters are reset.

Ese problema no afectará la integridad de la base de datos, pero tal vez pueda afectar al planificador a tomar malas decisiones pues el recolector de estadisticas no pueda recolectar su informacion.

En la [version 15](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/monitoring-stats.html#MONITORING-STATS-SETUP) este mecanismo de recolectar estadiscas cambió y ese error puede que ya no lo veas

> Cumulative statistics are collected in shared memory. Every PostgreSQL process collects statistics locally, then updates the shared data at appropriate intervals. When a server, including a physical replica, shuts down cleanly, a permanent copy of the statistics data is stored in the pg_stat subdirectory, so that statistics can be retained across server restarts. In contrast, when starting from an unclean shutdown (e.g., after an immediate shutdown, a server crash, starting from a base backup, and point-in-time recovery), all statistics counters are reset.

[Aqui](https://www.postgresql.fastware.com/blog/how-postgresql-improved-statistics-collector-in-the-latest-version) hay un blog hablando del tema:

Comment: Hola Anthony, estaba controlando i file di LOG y encontrè este error: "could not rename temporary statistics file "xxx/global.tmp" to "xxxx/global.stat": Permission denied". No es que faltan permissos sobre la carpeta?

Comment: no creo que sea de que falter permisos, el servidor esta en windiws? echale un vistazo a esto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30846804/postgresql-statistics-issue-could-not-rename-temporary-statistics-file/32193782#32193782

Comment: Si, el servidor està en Windows Server 2022 21H2

Comment: Ahí en ese enlace que te puse está el motivo de  el problema en Windows, como te comentaba no es crítico pero te puede afectar el rendimiento